How to approach a skid-steer point-to-point navigation with high precision arrival
I'm working on a problem where a skid-steer base needs to reliably and accurately approach points that are 1.5 to 2.0 meters apart. The base is equipped with high-quality GNSS and RTK receivers, providing accurate position and heading estimates. I can assume there won't be any obstacles. My experience with robot navigation is somewhat limited, as I've only implemented a couple of ROS-based skid-steer robots using move_base, where precision was never a priority.
Does anyone have ideas on how to approach this problem? I was considering using PID heading/velocity control, but I'm wondering if there's another widely used approach that I might not be aware of.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
